# Determining the particular number in $O(n)$ time and space (worst case)

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

$\newcommand\ldotd{\mathinner{..}}$Given that $A[1\ldotd n]$ are integers such that $0\le A[k]\le m$ for all $1\le k\le n$, and the occurrence of each number except a particular number in $A[1\ldotd n]$ is an odd number. Try to find the number whose occurrence is an even number.

There is an $\Theta(n\log n)$ algorithm: we sort $A[1\ldotd n]$ into $B[1\ldotd n]$, and break $B[1\ldotd n]$ into many pieces, whose elements' value are the same, therefore we can count the occurrence of each element.

I want to find a worst-case-$O(n)$-time-and-$O(n)$-space algorithm.

Supposing that $m=\Omega(n^{1+\epsilon})$ and $\epsilon>0$, therefore radix sort is not acceptable.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\xor}{xor}$
Binary bitwise operations are acceptable, for example, $A[1]\xor A[2]$.

Comment: Aryabhata's answer below shows that the general case is not good, but perhaps you have further restrictions available? A simple (but big) restriction would be to enforce that all the entries in the array are $O(n)$ in size. This would give a pretty trivial linear algorithm.

Comment: @LukeMathieson: I deleted that answer, as I am not yet convinced that [the paper I cited](http://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/6345/1/82-505.pdf) will work without any modification, and besides, OP seems to be interested only in the uniform cost RAM model.

Comment: @Aryabhata: hehe, well the answer that's not there then! Out of interesting, and perhaps useful for Frank, what did you think was the problem with adapting the result in the paper? A quick skim suggested it applied, but I obviously didn't read into it.

Comment: @LukeMathieson: The fact that the other elements need to appear an odd number of times in the current problem. Since, I skimmed over the proof too...

Comment: It would be interesting if you are interested in theoretic results or in practical solutions. From the theory point of view, my first quick response is, that you **can** sort a list of integers faster than $O(n\log n)$. There is a [deterministic algorithm by Han](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=975984) that runs in $O(\log\log n)$ time. For randomized algorithms, even better results are known, e.g. Han and Thorup have found a $O(n \sqrt{\log\log n})$ expected time algorithm. However, I think that your problem shouldn't require sorting.

Comment: What's funny is, that if you look at the opposite setting (find the only odd occurrence), then you get the result by XORing all entries of $A$.

Comment: @A.Schulz For that (opposite setting), I mentioned $\xor$ in my text.

Comment: Are the numbers themselves odd, or just the number of occurances?

Comment: @Joe They are arbitrary.

Comment: @Aryabhata: thank you very much for that citation. I don't think it can help at all in this case, because we are not looking for a majority element (the element in question could appear 2 times only, for instance), but it is interesting because the algorithm described in that paper is an (uncredited) ancestor of a generalization by [Schenker et al.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=762473) which is very well known. Thank you!

Comment: @Jérémie: Glad to have helped! btw, that paper deals with an element repeating more than $n/k$ times, including the case $k=n$. So it might be relevant, but might need some modification.

Comment: @FrankScience: Are your numbers necessarily integers?  Or could they be rationals?  Or reals?  Or elements of an abstract totally ordered set that supports $O(1)$-time comparisons?  (If you do mean "integers", please change the question to read "integers" instead of "numbers".)

Comment: @JeffE Well, integers, but any data structure whose length is invariable in computer could be considered as some integers.

Comment: @FrankScience: Sure, but if $A[i]$ is a rational number (for example), the inequality $0\le A[i] \le m$ doesn't tell you much about the number of bits in $A[i]$.

Comment: @JeffE Oh, yes, therefore I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea for a simple algorithm; just count all occurrences!

1. Find $m = \max A$. -- time $\Theta(n)$
2. "Allocate" array $C[0..m]$. -- time $O(1)$¹
3. Iterate over $A$ and increase $C[x]$ by one whenever you find $A[\_]=x$. If $C[x]$ was $0$, add $x$ to a linear list $L$. -- time $\Theta(n)$
4. Iterate over $L$ and find the element $x_e$ with $C[x_e]$ even. -- time $O(n)$.
5. Return $x_e$.

All in all, this gives you a linear-time algorithm which may use (in the sense of allocating) lots of memory. Note that being able to random-access $C$ in constant time independently of $m$ is crucial here.

An additional $O(n)$ bound on space is more difficult with this approach; I don't know of any dictionary data-structure that offers $O(1)$ time lookup. You can use hash-tables for which here are implementations with $O(1 + k/n)$ *expected* lookup time ($n$ the table's size, $k$ the number of stored elements) so you can get arbitrarily good with linear space -- in expectation. If all values in $A$ map to the same hash value, you are screwed.

---

1. On a RAM, this is implicitly done; all we need is the start position and maybe the end position.

Answer (score 0):

An almost trivial solution - which uses however $\Theta(n)$ space - is to use a hash map. Recall that a hash map has amortized runtime $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for adding and looking up elements.

Hence, we can use the following algorithm:

1. Allocate a hash map $H$. Iterate over $A$. For each element $i \in A$, increase the number of occurences seen, i.e. $H(i)++$.
2. Iterate through the key set of the hash map, and check which of the keys has an even count of occurences.

Now this is a simple algorithm which doesn't really use any large trick, but sometimes even this suffices. If not, you might want to specifiy what space restrictions you impose.

Comment: I would still like to know, if there is a non-randomized $O(n)$ time algorithm using polynomial space. In particular, is there any theoretical evidence that finding the only even-occurring item is harder than finding the only odd-occurring item?

Comment: @A.Schulz I think that it is the $O(n)$-expected-time algorithm by using hash table. I remember that somebody told me an $O(n)$-algorithm (or for some special case, say, odd=1 and even=2) maybe with stack, but I cannot recall it.

Comment: Not every hashtable implementation has this property; usually, lookup is not $O(1)$, not even amortized (afaik). In fact, a [prior discussion](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/249/when-is-hash-table-lookup-o1) has not yielded any implementation that has constant time lookup. Can you be more specific?