# Hashing and number of comparisons

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, hash-tables

Say, I want to put N objects into a hash table. How do I figure out how big the size of the table needs to be to have K comparisons on average when the table is: half full? three quarters full? all but last full?

Basically, this is due to me not really understanding the theory. I tried googling it, but didn't get it either. Can I have an explanation even a monkey would understand?

Comment: What kind of hash table? There are hundreds of them and they all have different properties.

Answer (score 4):

This explanation is for the *Homo sapiens sapiens* subspecies of *Cercopithecidae* (old world monkeys).  For an explanation suitable for other subspecies you'll have to try [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

I'll assume you are talking about [collision resolution by open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing), and [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) to determine the probe sequence.  Further we'll assume that the hash functions are good (that is: that they are essentially producing uniformly distributed, independent random integers.)

We will use $N$ for the number of objects already in the hash table, $M$ for the total number of buckets in the hash table and $\alpha = N/M$ as the [*load factor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics).  The load factor is the fraction of buckets that are already taken, and is really the important thing here.

If I try to insert a new item in a hash table with load factor $\alpha$ what is the probability that I will get a collision on my first probe?  Answer: $\alpha$.  Thus the probability that I find an open bucket on my first probe is $1-\alpha$.

What is the probability that I will find an open bucket on exactly my second probe?  Well the probability that I failed to find an open bucket on my first probe is $\alpha$ and the probability that I succeed on my second probe is $1-\alpha$, which gives a total probability of $\alpha (1-\alpha)$.

What is the probability that I will find an open bucket on exactly my third probe?  Well the probability that I failed to find an open bucket on my first and second probes is $\alpha^2$, and the probability that I succeed on my third probe is $1-\alpha$ so I have a total probability of $\alpha^2 (1-\alpha)$.

I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, so that's good enough for me to assume that the pattern holds for all positive integers.  That is I've just "proved" that the probability I will take $k$ probes to find an open bucket is
$$ p(k) = \alpha^{k-1} (1-\alpha). $$

(Exercise: make sure that this is a good probability by showing that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha^{k-1}(1-\alpha)=1$.)  Now what's the *expected* number of probes to find an open bucket?

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   E[\mathrm{number\ of\ probes}] &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p(k) \\
                                  &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^{k-1}(1-\alpha) \\
                                  &=& (1-\alpha)\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^{k-1} \\
                                  &=& \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^k.
\end{eqnarray}$$

I look up [this series on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Low-order_polylogarithms) and see that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^k = \alpha / (1-\alpha)^2$ so

$$ E[\mathrm{number\ of\ probes}] = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}.  $$

Comment: Please check if you want to add your answer (maybe in modified form) to the [older question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/249/98).