# How does a hash table not require all the keys to be looked through to find a value, i.e. O(N)?

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, hash-tables

Before starting, I want to say that I understand time complexity, and I understand how a hash table is considered O(1) vs an array having a time comp. of O(N) in terms of what you learn. What I don't understand is *why* looking up something in a hash table is not O(N).

Surely, just because you know the `key`, you still have to look your way through the data structure to find it. An analogy might be to knowing someone's name in order to find their phone number in a phone book: you can't just open the book **exactly** on their name; you still have to work your way through to find their location.

*Tl;dr: I want to know *how* a hash table can retrieve a `value` without having to look for said `value` through all the `keys`:`values` before it.*

Comment: Does [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/249/when-is-hash-table-lookup-o1) answers your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, a hash table opens the "book" **exacty** (or at least close by, in some terms) where it needs to.

The better analogy is like accessing a list of values with an index: If you have a book list of $100$ people and their phone numbers, and you want the $37$'th person's number, you know exactly where to search it in the book - you don't have to go through all of it.

This is exactly what a hash table does: it encodes the "name" into an index using a hash function.

Comment: This actually clears everything up. I thought I was stupid for asking, but I hadn't found an answer like this, one that just *made sense*. Or maybe I did and just was just oblivious to it. Regardless, thank you, Nir.

Comment: Glad I could help you! :)

Comment: An old joke from old times when people had phonebooks: "I asked you for the phone number of Mr. Smith three hours ago, what takes you so long?" "I'm going through it as fast as I can, but I'm still only at the letter D".

Answer (score -1):

In a hash table, we take the key, and then from the key we calculate at which place in the table it should be stored. So you just look at that single place, and usually that's where the key is stored.

It's a bit more complicate. Since there are more possible keys than entries in the table, there must be keys that "should" be stored in the same place. So it is possible that a different key is stored in that place. So there is a second formula that calculates alternative places for the key, and they will be visited until the key is found or an empty space (which means the key is not there).

If you make the table large enough compared to the number of keys stored, you will have an average of two or less accesses.